# Using BeautifulSoup for html scraping

Tags: html, python-2.7

So i'm trying to make a program that tells the user how far away voyager 1 is from the Earth, NASA has this info on their website here http://voyager.jpl.nasa.gov/where/index.html...
I can't seem to manage to get the information within the div, here's the div:  `<div id="voy1_km">Distance goes here</div>`

my current program is as follows : `

```
import requests
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup


url = "http://voyager.jpl.nasa.gov/where/index.html"
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
test = soup.find('div', {'id' : 'voy1_km'})

print test
```

So long story short, How do I get the div contents?

Comment: What is the output? Try to print response html and soup, to check if it's breaking anywhere

Comment: It just outputs <div id="voy1_km">...</div>

Comment: Check source, <div id="voy1_km"></div> has nothing in it. The changing value is being provided by JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you can see from the webpage itself, the distance keep changing which is actually driven by a [Javascript](http://voyager.jpl.nasa.gov/Scripts/distance.js). You can maybe just read the javascrip code so you don't even need to scrape to get the distance... (I hate websites using Javascript as much as you:) )

If you really want to get the number off their website. You can use Selenium.

```
# pip install selenium 
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://voyager.jpl.nasa.gov/where/index.html")
time.sleep(5)
elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("tr_dark")
print elem.text
driver.close()
```

Here is the output:

```
Distance from Earth
19,964,147,071 KM
133.45208042 AU
```

Of course, please refer to the terms&conditions of their website regarding to what level you can scrape their website and distribute the data.

Comment: Thanks this works, is there any way to run this from an OS like ububtu server? as far as I can tell it errors out due to the lack of web browser

Comment: Sure, please refer to [this](http://scraping.pro/use-headless-firefox-scraping-linux/) article of how to set up headless browser.

Answer (score 0):

The bigger question is why even bother scraping it. If you dive a bit deeper into the [Javascript file](http://voyager.jpl.nasa.gov/Scripts/distance.js), you can repeat its calculation in a very simple manner:

```
import time

epoch_0 = 1445270400
epoch_1 = 1445356800

dist_0_v1 = 19963672758.0152
dist_1_v1 = 19966727483.2612

current_time = time.time()

current_dist_km_v1 = ( ( ( current_time - epoch_0 ) / ( epoch_1 - epoch_0 ) ) * ( dist_1_v1 - dist_0_v1 ) ) + dist_0_v1

print("{:,.0f} KM".format(current_dist_km_v1))
```